# cylinder has a weird shape

Tags: modeling

I' having a trouble with a shape of my newly addded cylinder. It's just not round. Problem might be a huge and complicated mesh near it, but I need it there for a reference. In picture you can see that the edges are rough.[image]

Comment: Looks like floating point precision problem. Make sure your model isn't very far from the origin or very large, and change the camera clip distances in the view panel of the N panel

Comment: @Gorgious that comment would be better as an answer